# The best solution for table relation in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am developing a platform with Laravel and have trouble connecting realtion between multiple tables .The tables are as follows :

1. Order
2. Service field
3. Service field value

Each order has several service fields and each service field is for several order.(Service field and order relationship n=>n)
The relationship between service and service value 1=>n ,Each fields service field has several service values.

**Order model:**

```
public function serviceFields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ServiceFields::class);
}
```

**Service field model:**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}

public function ServicebFieldValue()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ServiceFieldValue::class);
}
```

**Service field value model:**

```
public function serviceField()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ServiceFields::class);
}
```

For each order, several services field must be stored, there is a many to many middle table, and I do not have a solution for storing the service field values of an order, where this service field values  should be stored and what the type of relationship should be?

Comment: N:N/many to many relationship requires defining `belongsToMany` relationships on both models, and there has to be a pivot table (`order_service_field`) that connects the two tables, `orders` and `service_fields`.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I have trouble storing Service field value
Do I need to add a table to store the Service field value?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken there are 2 possible options here, first which I think might be easiest in your case if to use has many through relation ship which reads like so:

Order has many service field values through service value - additional fields will be required in your database, have a look at docs on how to achieve that and let me know if you still don't know https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Alternatively this is a good candidate for polymorphic relationship, where service field can be part of many orders via pivot table, in your case it'd be called service_fielable (something like that) which contains order_id, service_fieldable_id (service field id) and a type - which will effectively be a string of service field class

Here are docs for polymorphic relationships:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Then obviously you need to connect service field value to the service field vis has many (one to many) relationship so - service field has many service field values and service field value belongs to service field

Hope it all makes sense, let me know if any issues I will set up dev env and try to code it for you